# Program type already present: android.support.constraint.BuildConfig

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

**build.gradle (Module: app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "tk.megh.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 'P'
        targetSdkVersion 'P'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}



dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

Well i think i know what's causing the error, if you look at the dependencies there are two redundant packages with different names

**com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0
androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.0**

But i can't remove either of them because they are used by some packages. I'm a novice in android development, so i don't have much idea about any workarounds.

if i remove

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
```

i get this error while debugging:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{tk.megh.myapplication/tk.megh.myapplication.MainActivity}: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file 
line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
```

and if i remove

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.0'
```

i get the following error while debugging:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{tk.megh.myapplication/tk.megh.myapplication.DisplayMessageActivity}: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: 
Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

**Additional Details:**

imports of *MainActivity.java*:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
```

imports of *DisplayMessageActivity.java*:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why can't you remove either of them? They are essentially the same, only google started to move code to a different place "androidx" and will start adopting that as the sole place for updating the support library (and other componets for that matter).

Comment: Remove one of them and adjust the references from your code.

Comment: Remove androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.0

Comment: cant use the editor for constraint layout on android p at present?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The errors indicate that you're using the `ConstraintLayout` in your layout `xml` files.

Keep only one version of the library and make sure, that you are using that version's ConstraintLayout in your xmls.

So, if you keep `androidx`, check your layout files and make sure, you are using `androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout` there, and **not** `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: Oh okay. Didn't think it was with the layout. Now i know,  Thank you for that.

Comment: Android Studio 3.2 (canary 14) adds the androidx constraint layout when you (from the visual editor) convert a view group into CLayout. Must be a “bug” or something that will go away once androidx. package becomes mainstream and the other is removed. If you were already using CL 1.1.0 (from support), which is what a new project template does for you (includes that in gradle), then you will see this conflict.

Comment: I found I was using all the proper matching xmls and ConstraintLayout in my xml file. It was in the build.gradle where I had both of them included as dependencies. Once I removed that, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful not to reference `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout` and `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout` at the same time. Settle on one (preferably androidx), remove the other, and make sure the package names are consistent in your layout files too. That fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue.
I was using two different versions for android.arch.core library.So,fixing those versions helped me.Try to use one version throughout your application.Hope it helps someone.

Thanks